# Wordpress WP-Config and Functions?

Tags: wordpress

Working on a friend's site - that had no Editor or Plugin control in the WordPress CMS. I go to WP-Config and change:

`define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );`

`define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );`

both to `false` which works fine.

Then I look in `Functions.php` (in the theme) and see at the top:

`define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );`

`define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );`

Does this actually work? It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, `define()` is used to define a **constant**. Constants are so named because they cannot be redefined by subsequent `define()` calls using the same identifier.

So those definitions in `functions.php` are just (probably silently) ignored. Maybe they show up in a log file somewhere, though.